# PHP EC2 Wait until volume is available

Tags: php, amazon-ec2

This is a code snippet I am using to manipulate my EC2 instance.

```
$ec2 = Aws::factory(array(
                'key' => $key,
                'secret' => $secret,
                'region' => $region)
            )->get('ec2', true);

$volId = createVol();// This step creates the volume correctly
$ec2->waitUntil('__VolumeStatus', array(
        'VolumeIds' => array($volId),
        'waiter.success.value' => VolumeState::AVAILABLE
    ));

attachVolume();//Error
```

The problem is attachVolume function is throwing error that **volume is not available** that means **waitUntil** function is not working correctly. Is there somethings wrong with the way I called this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the EC2 API is eventually consistent. So waiters are working correctly but sometimes the API is returning the wrong statuses

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/query-api-troubleshooting.html

http://blog.cloudfoundry.com/2013/06/18/dealing-with-eventual-consistency-in-the-aws-ec2-api/

Comment: Also check this link from the docs http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/query-api-troubleshooting.html